Countable elementary substructure of $H_\kappa$
For infinite cardinal $\kappa$, let $H_\kappa=\{x:|\text{trcl}(\{x\})|<\kappa\}$. It's well-known that $H_\kappa\subseteq V_\kappa$. When working with elementary substructures of such $H_\kappa$, I accidentally came up with a "proof" leading to contradiction, but I can't quite figure out what's wrong with it:
Let $\kappa=(\beth_{\omega_1})^+$; then $H_{\omega_1}\in H_{\kappa}$. Let $X\prec H_\kappa$ be a countable elementary substructure. One can show that $\omega+1\subset X$, and from there one can deduce $X\cap H_{\omega_1}:=M$ is transitive. It's obvious enough that $\omega+1\subset X$ by elementarity; let $x\in y\in H_{\omega_1}\cap X$, we want to see $x\in H_{\omega_1}\cap X$. Consider the sentence "there's a surjection from $\omega$ onto $y$"; it holds in $H_\kappa$ and thus in $X$; let $f\in X$ be a witness, by elementarity $f$ is a surjection in $H_\kappa$ (and so it really is a surjection); say $x=f(n)$, and since $X\models \exists z,z=f(n)$, we have $x\in X\cap H_{\omega_1}$.
Let $\varphi(v)$ be
$$v=\{x:|\text{trcl}(\{x\})|\leq\omega\}$$ $H_\kappa\models\exists A,\varphi(A)$, so $X\models\exists A,\varphi(A)$. But the witness $A$ in $X$ must be $M$, so $M\in X$, and $X\models\varphi(M)$. By elementarity, $H_\kappa\models\varphi(M)$. But this is impossible as the solution to $\varphi$ in $H_\kappa$ is precisely $H_{\omega_1}$, and $M\neq H_{\omega_1}$ since $M$ is countable!

$M$ will not in general be transitive, in particular we have that $M$ will not contain all of the ordinals below $\omega_1$ but will contain $\omega_1$.

@GiorgioGenovesi Note that $\omega_1\notin H_{\omega_1}$ since it has uncountable cardinality, so $\omega_1\notin M=X\cap H_{\omega_1}$; also, you can give a rigorous proof that $M$ is transitive

Yes, sorry I mixed $X$ and $M$ up. You are correct, M is transitive.


But the witness $A$ in $X$ must be $M$, so $M\in X$, and $X\models\varphi(M)$.

No, being that $H_{\omega_1}$ is a definable element of $H_\kappa,$ $H_{\omega_1}$ is an element of $X,$ and serves as the witness to $\varphi$ in $X.$ Of course, according to (the very non-transitive) $X$, the only elements of $H_{\omega_1}$ are the elements of $M$, but that doesn't mean $M$ is the set of hereditarily countable sets according to $X.$ (If you Mostowski collapse $X$, $H_{\omega_1}$ will go to $M$, but none of its elements will move, since as you show, $M$ is already transitive.)
